# How does a GLSL sampler determine the minification, and thus the mipmap level, of a texture?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, mipmaps

I am working with OpenGL ES (via WebGL), but I think this question is applicable to the full OpenGL profile as well.

Suppose I create an OpenGL texture with full mipmap levels, and I set its TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST. Also suppose that I have a fragment shader that samples this texture. The mipmap level is chosen based on the degree of minification of the texture, but how is the degree of minification chosen?

In my case, I am synthesizing (inside the shader) the texture coordinates that I use to sample my texture. In fact, my texture coordinates are not based on any incoming varyings. Even though I have mipmapping enabled on this texture, it doesn't seem to have any effect. Is this expected? Do I need to compute the LOD myself and use the bias parameter to texture2D? (there is no texture2DLOD, since I'm using ES)

Comment: I'm not sure how you could possibly be computing a non-constant value without using some form of varying information, since the only information that is different in different invocations of the same share are varyings (remember: gl_FragCoord is a varying too). So how are you computing them? Even a noise function or RNG needs something to key on.

Comment: See also: ["How does opengl decide which mip level to use?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523488/how-does-opengl-decide-which-mip-level-to-use)

Comment: @Nicol I was hoping to keep the question simple by omitting detail. I supply my fragment shader with two textures. The first texture is a look-up table into the second texture, which has the actual image data. So I use a varying to sample the first texture, but the content of that texture is used to compute the coordinates for the next lookup. So I do suppose the second texture's coordinates are based on a varying, but the math in between is not simple.

Comment: @Stefan Honestly, I did search! All I could find were "how do I sample a particular mipmap level". Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blocks of adjacent pixels are computed in parallel. (IIRC the PowerVR chips do a 4x4 block at a time, for example.) When you call texture2D in your fragment shader, the sampler is fetching all 16 samples for all 16 pixels at once, and so has adjacency information needed to calculate the minification level. This is part of why it's so important for adjacent pixels to sample from nearby areas of the texture.

Note that this only applies to fragment shaders. In vertex shaders the first mipmap level is always used, (unless you use the Lod version of texture2D is used.)

Comment: RE PowerVR chips: AFAIK these use 2x2 blocks for the filter gradient calculations much like the chips from other vendors as this is what is specified in various APIs

Answer (score 3):

You are allowed to compute texture coordinates arbitrarily, and the shader will act accordingly... within one restriction. Your computations cannot involve any conditional logic. They can involve varyings, uniforms, constants, values sampled from other textures, whatever you want. But the moment you slip so much as a ?: operator in there (let alone an if-statement), you're in trouble.

And since you're in OpenGL ES land, you don't really have the tools to get yourself out of that trouble. Desktop GL 3.0 gives you the `textureGrad` set of functions, which allows you to compute gradients before reaching the conditional logic. But without that, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is interesting, but it doesn't really address my underlying question (how is the mipmap level determined?)